# How to check if p:message already exists for a component?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My question is that is there any way by which we can check if a message is already present for a specific Primefaces component,and if not then only add message for that component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the queued messages for a specific component via the `FacesContext` object. The following code should work:

```
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); //obtain a reference to the FacesContext
     String desiredClientId = "componentId"; //You should already have the client side id of the component you want to operate with
     Iterator<FacesMessage> messageQueue =  context.getMessages(desiredClientId); //Obtain an Iterator for a List of possible queued messages for the component id you've provided.
     if(messageQueue.hasNext()){
      //the component has messages queued, do whatever you want
      }
      else{
      no messages, do whatever you want
      }
```